# convert mahout random forest classification output to readable

Tags: java, hadoop, classification, mahout, random-forest

I am learning the mahout random forest with tutorial in mahout site:
http://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/partial-implementation.html

but when all jobs finishes successfully my output file is like this:

@1@.@0@

@1@.@0@

@0@.@0@

@1@.@0@

@1@.@0@

@0@.@0@

@0@.@0@

@0@.@0@

how can I convert it to human readable output?

Comment: Not familiar with mahout but assume that you may override `toString` methods in you classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found that this numbers are the code of labels.

we can change them to labels.

after this code in TestForest.java example:

```
classifier.run();
```

get the results:

```
double[][] results = classifier.getResults();
```

the second column is the prediction. change it to label with this code:

```
Dataset dataset = Dataset.load(getConf(), datasetPath);
for (double[] res : results) {
    dataset.getLabelString(res[1]);
}
```